# How to handle firebase wrong email and password error in react native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, error-handling, firebase-authentication, expo

```
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  TextInput,
  Image,
  View,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Dimensions,
  SafeAreaView,
} from "react-native";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { StatusBar } from "expo-status-bar";
import { useNavigation } from "@react-navigation/native";
import Animated, {
  FadeIn,
  FadeInDown,
  FadeInUp,
} from "react-native-reanimated";
import Icon from "react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome";
import { signInWithEmailAndPassword } from "firebase/auth";
import { auth } from "../config/firebase";
import { setItem } from "../Utils/AsyncStorage";

const { width, height } = Dimensions.get("window");

export default function LoginScreen() {
  const [passwordVisible, setPasswordVisible] = React.useState(false);
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  const [emailError, setEmailError] = useState("");
  const [passwordError, setPasswordError] = useState("");
  const navigation = useNavigation();


  const handleLogin = async () => {
    setEmailError("");
    setPasswordError("");

    if (!email || !password) {
      if (!email) setEmailError("*Please enter email");
      if (!password) setPasswordError("*Please enter password");
      return;
    }

    try {
      await signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);
      navigation.navigate("Home");
      setItem("LoggedIn", "1");
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("Firebase error:", error);
      if (error.code === "auth/invalid-login-credentials") {
        if (error.message.includes("password")) {
          setPasswordError("*Wrong password, please try again");
        } else {
          setEmailError("*User not found, please sign up");
        }
      } else {
        console.log("Error occurred while login:", error.message);
      }
    }
  };

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.topContainer}>
      <StatusBar style="light" />

      <View style={styles.fields}>        
         
            <View style={{ flexDirection: "row", alignItems: "center" }}>
              <TextInput
                placeholder="Email Address"
                placeholderTextColor={"gray"}
                value={email}
                onChangeText={(text) => setEmail(text)}
                style={{ flex: 1 }}
              />
              <Icon
                name="envelope"
                size={17}
                color="grey"
                style={{ marginRight: 5 }}
              />
            </View>
          </Animated.View>
          <Text
            style={{
              color: "red",
              marginTop: -6,
              marginRight: "auto",
              marginLeft: 8,
              marginBottom: 5,
            }}
          >
            {emailError}
          </Text>

          <Animated.View
            entering={FadeInDown.delay(400).duration(1000).springify()}
            style={{
              backgroundColor: "#f0f0f0",
              padding: 13,
              borderRadius: 15,
              width: width * 0.87,
            }}
          >
            <View style={{ flexDirection: "row", alignItems: "center" }}>
              <TextInput
                placeholder="Enter password"
                placeholderTextColor={"gray"}
                value={password}
                onChangeText={(text) => setPassword(text)}
                secureTextEntry={!passwordVisible}
                style={{ flex: 1 }}
              />
              <TouchableOpacity
                onPress={() => setPasswordVisible(!passwordVisible)}
                style={{ padding: 4 }}
              >
                <Icon
                  name={passwordVisible ? "eye" : "eye-slash"}
                  size={20}
                  color="grey"
                />
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
          </Animated.View>
          <Text
            style={{
              color: "red",
              marginTop: -6,
              marginRight: "auto",
              marginLeft: 8,
            }}
          >
            {passwordError}
          </Text>

          <View className="ml-auto">
            <TouchableOpacity>
              <Animated.Text
                entering={FadeIn.delay(600).duration(1000).springify()}
                style={{
                  color: "#69ADC6",
                  fontSize: 13,
                  marginBottom: 35,
                  marginTop: -20,
                }}
              >
                Forgot Password?
              </Animated.Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>

          <Animated.View
            entering={FadeInDown.delay(600).duration(1000).springify()}
            style={{ width: width * 0.87 }}
          >
            <TouchableOpacity
              onPress={handleLogin}
              style={{
                backgroundColor: "#23286A",
                borderRadius: 15,
                marginBottom: 15,
                width: width * 0.87,
                padding: 12,
              }}
            >
<Text
                style={{
                  fontWeight: "bold",
                  color: "white",
                  fontSize: 20,
                  textAlign: "center",
                }}
              >
                Login
              </Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </Animated.View>
          
        </View>
      </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}
```

I've written this code, and the issue is that when an incorrect email is entered, it shows an error on the email field saying, "User not found, please sign up." However, when an incorrect password is entered, it doesn't show the "wrong password" error; instead, it still displays the "user not found" error on the email input field. How does Firebase handle the case of a wrong password?

Comment: On Firebase projects created since September 15, the [email enumeration protection](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/admin/email-enumeration-protection) is turned on by default. That makes it harder to steal your user's data, but *does* also mean the API gives different responses and less detailed error messages. For example, it is no longer possible to distinguish between an email address that is not registered and an invalid password - as you're trying to do here. For more, see my explanations on the questions I linked.